# fcm_django library Issue

Tags: django

I am trying to integrate Google Firebase with Django App. The error what i am facing is the makemigrations file get created in site packages of fcm_django and while migrating the model is not created in DB.

The Package I am using are below.

```
Babel==2.6.0
cairocffi==0.8.1
CairoSVG==2.1.3
certifi==2018.1.18
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
cssselect2==0.2.1
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==1.11
django-cors-headers==2.2.0
django-haystack==2.8.1
django-oauth-toolkit==1.0.0
django-oauth2-provider==0.2.6.1
django-phonenumber-field==2.0.1
django-rest-framework-docs==0.1.7
django-uuidfield==0.5.0
django-vinaigrette==1.1.1
djangorestframework==3.7.7
drfdocs==0.0.11
elasticsearch==6.3.0
fcm-django==0.2.19
future==0.16.0
gcloud==0.17.0
html5lib==1.0.1
httplib2==0.11.3
idna==2.6
ipaddress==1.0.22
jsonfield==2.0.2
jsonpickle==0.9.6
jws==0.1.3
oauth2client==3.0.0
oauthlib==2.0.7
pdfrw==0.4
phonenumbers==8.9.11
Pillow==5.1.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
protobuf==3.6.1
psycopg2==2.7.4
psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
pyasn1==0.4.4
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
pycparser==2.18
pyfcm==1.4.5
PyJWT==1.6.4
Pyphen==0.9.4
PySocks==1.6.8
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-jwt==2.0.1
pytz==2018.3
requests==2.19.1
requests-toolbelt==0.7.0
rsa==4.0
sendotp==0.0.4
shortuuid==0.5.0
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.11.0
tinycss2==0.6.1
twilio==6.16.3
urllib3==1.22
WeasyPrint==0.42.3
webencodings==0.5.1
```

Could Someone please let me know Why isn't this making the db structure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add the lib to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py`?

Comment: I have added in installed library..,

Comment: sorry installed apps....,

Comment: Are there any errors present when running `migrate`?

Comment: Nothing The migration File get created but on migrate, db is not altered or added. FCM Device Model fields are in migrations.

Comment: Note that 3rd party apps like `fcm_django` that have models come with the migrations for those models. So these migrations were not created when the `makemigrations` command was run.

Comment: No its getting created in the site package with migrations folder but not creating the db fields.